# How get list from SQL Server database with stored procedure and add to ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf

I need get list from my SQL Server database with a stored procedure and add all to combobox.

When I select any item from cBoxWhatLaws - the app connecting with database and gets relevant articles and add to cBoxArticleList.

`Helper.WhatLaws` returns `tableName`..

Stored procedure and database are ok, because all work with java application.
Adding to database from this application works too.

```
//Page.cs
private void cBoxWhatLaws_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cBoxWhatLaws.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        tableName = Helper.WhatLaws(cBoxWhatLaws.SelectedIndex);

        cBoxArticleList.Items.Clear();
        cBoxArticleList.Items.Add("Choose article:");

        if (MyDatabaseHelper.seeArtList(tableName).Count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Article list is empty.", "Empty list", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MyDatabaseHelper.seeArtList(tableName).Count; i++)
            {
                cBoxArticleList.IsEnabled = true;
                cBoxArticleList.Items.Add(MyDatabaseHelper.seeArtList(tableName).ElementAt(i).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

// MyDatabaseHelper
static SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=PrzepisyGry; Integrated Security=True;");

public static List<string> seeArtList(string przepisyGry)
{
    var artList = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("getArticleList", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nazwaTabeli", przepisyGry));

        sqlCon.Open();
        IDataReader result = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        int i = 0;

        while (result.Read())
        {
            artList.Add(result[i].ToString());
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error with get list", "Err", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    return artList;
}
```

The application has a problem with returning `artList` and shows an error:

> Error with get list > Index out of range

Comment: For debugging, set a breakpoint to examine the exception details. Or temporarily change you catch block to show the stack: `catch (Exception ex)             {
MessageBox.Show("Error with get list:" + ex.ToString(), "Err", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);`
}`

Comment: @DanGuzman Index out of range

Comment: The result index should be the column, not the row number. Try `artList.Add(result["YourColumnName"].ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

I have a answer. In MyDatabaseHelper.cs:

```
while (result.Read())
{
artList.Add(result[0].ToString()); // i -> 0 (for first column)
}
```